# How to replace all chars in the string except another string in this string

Tags: java, string

For example I have two strings

```
String a="aaabbbaaa";
String b="bbb";
```

I need to replace all chars in string a except String b

I need next result (for example we replace all "a" chars with "+"):
+++bbb+++

Comment: Go ,learn ,try then ask question.

Comment: String a can contain *any* character or it will just have a single other character?

Comment: Have you learnt about regex? Can you make a try with that first and come back for help...

Answer (score 2):

```
String a="aaabbbaaa";
String b="bbb";


String newA = "";
int i = 0;
while (i < a.indexOf(b)) {
  newA += "+";
  i++;
}

newA +=b;

i = a.lastIndexOf(b);
while (i < a.length()) {
  newA += "+";
  i++;
}
System.out.println(newA);
```

Comment: +1 for the *simplest* solution, but `i=...; while(i...){...;i++;}` could be written `for(i=...;i...;i++){...}`. Note that you also don't *have* to create a new string.

Comment: And you should use `a.indexOf(b) + b.length()` instead of `a.lastIndexOf(b)`

Answer (score 2):

For such purposes I always use an external library: [Apache-Commons-Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi). Within this package you have a huge bunch of well-tested and well-designed methods for String manipulation.

- StringUtils.replace(null, *, *)        = null
- StringUtils.replace("", *, *)          = ""
- StringUtils.replace("any", null, *)    = "any"
- StringUtils.replace("any", *, null)    = "any"
- StringUtils.replace("any", "", *)      = "any"
- StringUtils.replace("aba", "a", null)  = "aba"
- StringUtils.replace("aba", "a", "")    = "b"
- StringUtils.replace("aba", "a", "z")   = "zbz"

Answer (score 1):

Improved version of the very simple solution from [*@Shreyas Dave*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16688661/1439688):

```
String myReplace(String a, String b, char substitute) {
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(a.length());
    int i = 0;
    int pos = -1;
    while ((pos = a.indexOf(b, pos + 1)) >= 0) {
        for (; i < pos; ++i) { 
            result.append(substitute);         
        }
        result.append(b);
        i += b.length();
    }
    for (; i < a.length(); ++i) { 
        result.append(substitute);         
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Of course, it works only for the first occurrence. The fact that `b` can be present multiple times in `a` should be clarified in the OP.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Here is a new version that handle multiple occurrence of the string.

Answer (score 0):

At least this works:

```java
    String a = "axabbbababbbbbbbbb";
    String b = "bbb";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(a.length());
    for (int i = 0, alen = a.length(), blen = b.length(), last = alen - blen + 1; i < alen; i++) {
        if (i < last && b.equals(a.substring(i, i + blen))) {
            result.append(b);
            i += blen - 1;
        }
        else {
            result.append('+');
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you could do something like this:

```
public static String plussify(String data, String words) {
    return (" " + data).replaceAll(".((?:"+words+")+)?", "+$1").substring(1);
}
```

The added space prefix is needed to cater to corner cases where the string starts with a word that is not to be replaced. If this never occurs then all you need is `replaceAll`. The `words` string is used in the regex and as such needs to be escaped and sanitized accordingly. The syntax of `words` is `bbb` for a single string or `bbb|d|ff` for multiple strings (`bbb`, `d` and `ff`).

The regex works by consuming single characters and replacing them with `+`, if any character is followed by a whitelisted word, then that word is consumed as well (thereby stopping it from being replaced by `+`) and appended to the `+` put in place of the character preceeding the whitelisted word.

**Example:**

```
System.out.println(plussify("daaabbbffffbbabbd","bbb|d|ff"));

output: d+++bbbffff+++++d
```

Given we know the string does not start with any whitelisted word:

```
System.out.println("aaabbbaaa".replaceAll(".((?:bbb)+)?", "+$1"));
output: +++bbb+++
```